# Combine two fields in a query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, report

I'm building a report in Access of Job Quote Acceptability. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    tblSTATUS.Status, Count(tblJOB.StatusTypeID) AS CountOfStatusTypeID
FROM 
    tblSTATUS 
INNER JOIN 
    tblJOB ON tblSTATUS.StatusTypeID = tblJOB.StatusTypeID
GROUP BY 
    tblSTATUS.Status
HAVING 
    (((tblSTATUS.Status) = "Completed" OR 
      (tblSTATUS.Status) = "Accepted" OR 
      (tblSTATUS.Status) = "Rejected"));
```

And here are the results:

```
Status          CountofStatusTypeID
Accepted                 22
Completed                 4
Rejected                  3
```

Unfortunately, I need to combine the Accepted and Completed fields in the report, because they are both "accepted" jobs. I can't find a way to combine these two and still show the rejected value in the report. I know how to write a query to get either the Accept or Rejected results, but not sure how to combine them into something that can be used in Access reports.

Comment: Can you not add another field to the Status table?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work as you wanted?

```
SELECT "completed and accepted" as jobstatus, Count(tblJOB.StatusTypeID) AS CountOfStatusTypeID
FROM tblSTATUS INNER JOIN tblJOB ON tblSTATUS.StatusTypeID = tblJOB.StatusTypeID
where tblSTATUS.Status="Completed" Or tblSTATUS.Status="Accepted" 
union
SELECT tblSTATUS.Status as jobstatus, Count(tblJOB.StatusTypeID) AS CountOfStatusTypeID
FROM tblSTATUS INNER JOIN tblJOB ON tblSTATUS.StatusTypeID = tblJOB.StatusTypeID
where tblSTATUS.Status="Rejected";
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Access had trouble with the new jobstatus column because it was not "part of an aggregate function". Access has got to be one of the most frustrating programs I've ever used. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    newtblSTATUS.newstatus, Count(tblJOB.StatusTypeID) AS CountOfStatusTypeID
FROM 
    (
SELECT 
    iif(tblSTATUS.Status='Rejected','Rejected','Accepted') as newstatus, tblSTATUS.StatusTypeID 
FROM 
    tblSTATUS 
where tblSTATUS.Status in ("Completed","Accepted","Rejected")) as newtblSTATUS 
INNER JOIN 
    tblJOB ON newtblSTATUS.StatusTypeID = tblJOB.StatusTypeID
GROUP BY 
     newtblSTATUS.newstatus
```